# Advance on salary request in odoo

Tags: odoo-9

I want to create a advance salary module in Odoo v9. 
I don't think that there is a module available in odoo for the same.
Functionality goes like this.
An employee request's for advance salary. The request then goes to Team lead and other senior officer like Manager for approve or refuse. 
Can anyone suggest me a way that how can I achieve this task.

Answer (score 0):

There is a module for that:

https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/9.0/employee_advance_salary/

...with a cost.

Maybe you can work on a free version, at lease you have soomething to base on.